# How to better model customer attrition?

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, churn

I've just started practicum work for a SaaS company, and trying to build a customer attrition (binary classification) model for enterprise SaaS product with a target variable indicating whether or not a customer churned after their annual renewal cycle by encoding 1/0 based on their historical renewal status.

At a high level there are 3 types of features: Adoption features, engagement features, and fixed characteristics. The training dataset contains monthly snapshots of adoption and engagement features. Thus every customer will have at least 12 records in our system, if they have churned after their first annual subscriptions, and if a customer has renewed for another 12 months, then they would have at least 24 records, etc.

Adoption features are the known to be the most important features for predicting customer churn outcomes and features in this category are things like % of activated accounts, Monthly active user count, etc. Engagement features are things like the amount of self-service online videos customers in a particular account have watched, number of certificates earned, number of interactions a customer had with customer success product experts.

The problem is that using the base classification model construct of `churn(1/0) ~ adoption features + engagement features`, I'm not seeing any significant contributions from engagement features, but I think there are some lag effect where improvements to engagement features lead to the improvements to adoption features. For example, customer success interactions lead to some improvements to adoption features but not during the exact months when the interactions happen, but in the next 1~2 months after the interactions.

Are there any models that would better represent this dynamic? From my initial research I might use a technique like vector autoregressive regression to model this, but not sure if that's the way to go.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!